# I have a question about errors that occur due to specifying arguments in Unit Tests

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

I am creating and running unit tests for a class that implements a use case for searching geography.

search_location_usecase_impl.dart

```dart
class SearchLocationUsecaseImpl implements SearchLocationUsecase {
  SearchLocationUsecaseImpl({
    required GeographySearchRepository geographySearchRepository,
    required String geographySearchApiKey,
    required FirebaseCrashlytics firebaseCrashlyticsInstance,
  })  : _geographySearchRepository = geographySearchRepository,
        _geographySearchApiKey = geographySearchApiKey,
        _firebaseCrashlyticsInstance = firebaseCrashlyticsInstance;

  final GeographySearchRepository _geographySearchRepository;
  final String _geographySearchApiKey;
  final FirebaseCrashlytics _firebaseCrashlyticsInstance;

  @override
  Future<LatLng> execute({required String requestPath}) async {
    try {
      final resultLocation = await _geographySearchRepository.searchLocation(
        requestPath: requestPath + _geographySearchApiKey,
      );
      if (resultLocation == null) {
        throw SearchLocationException();
      }
      return resultLocation.toLatLng();
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      await _firebaseCrashlyticsInstance.log(SearchLocationException().code);
      throw SearchLocationException();
    }
  }
}
```

[unit test]
search_location_usecase_impl_test.dart

```
void main() {
  late MockGeographySearchRepository mockGeographySearchRepository;
  late SearchLocationUsecase searchLocationUsecase;
  final fakeFirebaseCrashlytics = MockFirebaseCrashlytics();

  setUp(() {
    mockGeographySearchRepository = MockGeographySearchRepository();
    searchLocationUsecase = SearchLocationUsecaseImpl(
      geographySearchRepository: mockGeographySearchRepository,
      geographySearchApiKey: TestConst.geographySearchApiKey,
      firebaseCrashlyticsInstance: fakeFirebaseCrashlytics,
    );
  });

  group('[UnitTest: SearchLocationUsecase]', () {
    test('', () async {
      final resultLocation = ModelConst.resultLocation.toLatLng();
      // Arrange
      when(
        mockGeographySearchRepository.searchLocation(
          requestPath: TestConst.requestPath,
        ),
      ).thenAnswer((_) async => ModelConst.resultLocation);

      // Act
      final result = await searchLocationUsecase.execute(
        requestPath: TestConst.requestPath,
      );
      debugPrint(result.toString());

      // Assert
      expect(result, resultLocation);
    });
  });
}
```

When running this test, the following error message is displayed.

```
  Instance of 'SearchLocationException'
  package:____/usecase/search_location_usecase_impl.dart 31:7  SearchLocationUsecaseImpl.execute
```

To resolve this issue, you can make adjustments to this part of [search_location_usecase_impl.dart], and the test will run smoothly.

search_location_usecase_impl.dart

```
      final resultLocation = await _geographySearchRepository.searchLocation(
        requestPath: requestPath,  // [+ _geographySearchApiKey] delete
      );
```

Why does changing the way arguments are specified make the unit test run successfully?

Also, even if you change the Mock argument specification as shown below, the same error will occur.

```
      when(
        mockGeographySearchRepository.searchLocation(
          requestPath: TestConst.requestPath + geographySearchApiKey,
        ),
      ).thenAnswer((_) async => ModelConst.resultLocation);
```

Comment: When you register a stub for a mock, you specify what arguments the stub expects and what the stub should return.  The arguments *must match exactly*.  If the arguments do not match, then the stub will just return `null` (and your code throws `SearchLocationException` when `resultLocation == null`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Is there any official documentation that states that the arguments must match exactly?

Comment: Also, even if you change the Mock argument specification as shown below, the same error will occur.
```
 when(
        mockGeographySearchRepository.searchLocation(
          requestPath: TestConst.requestPath + geographySearchApiKey,
        ),
      ).thenAnswer((_) async => ModelConst.resultLocation);
```

Comment: If the arguments don't match exactly, how would you expect it to work?  If you create a stub for `mockObject.method('foo')`, why would you expect it to match when `mockObject.method('bar')` is called?  Per https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#argument-matchers: "If an argument other than an `ArgMatcher` (like `any`, `anyNamed`, `argThat`, `captureThat`, etc.) is passed to a mock method, then the `equals` matcher is used for argument matching."

Comment: Do you mean `TestConst.requestPath` + `TestConst.geographySearchApiKey`?  If that doesn't work either, then your `execute` function is being called with something else.  I'd suggest having your `execute` function do: `debugPrint(equestPath + _geographySearchApiKey)` and verifying that it's the same as `TestConst.requestPath` + `TestConst.geographySearchApiKey`.